# how do I implement del of an object that supports __getitem__ in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a toy hash table in Python and can't figure out how to implement the `del myDict[key]` syntax.

I think if I wanted to delete the entire object, I can just implement the `__del__` method which takes in `self` as an argument.

But how do I implement deletion by a specific key?

Using Python 3.7

Thanks!

Comment: "I think if I wanted to delete the entire object, I can just implement the `__del__` method which takes in `self` as an argument." - no, that's not what `del` means. `__del__` is a finalizer, not a `del` hook. You cannot manually delete objects in Python.

Comment: Deletion in python works a lot like unlinking in Unix. The file/object doesn't disappear until all the links/bindings are gone (and sometimes not even then).